# How to match shortest content by key words?

Tags: regex, perl

I am a Perl beginner and I have the following question

How to using Perl regular expression to match shortest content by key words?
For example:

```
my $txt='RMS Power                     :  [   0.00]>[   2.83]<[   4.00]dBm        [PASS]';
```

I hope to get the following results：

```
$1: RMS Power
$2: 0.00
$3: 2.83
$4: 4.00
$5: dBm
```

My code:

```
my $txt='RMS Power                     :  [   0.00]>[   2.83]<[   4.00]dBm        [PASS]';

$re='.*?(\[([^\]]+)\]).*?(\[([^\]]+)\]).*?(\[([^\]]+)\])';
if ($txt =~ m/$re/is)
{
    $sbraces1=$1;
    $sbraces2=$2;
    $sbraces3=$3;
    $sbraces4=$4;
    $sbraces5=$5;
    print "$sbraces1 $sbraces2 $sbraces3 $sbraces4 $sbraces5 \n";
}
```

The above is my code，output is "[   0.00]    0.00 [   2.83]    2.83 [   4.00] ", I also want to get “RMS Power”，“dBm” string.

I would greatly appreciate it if you you can give me some advice.

Comment: What have you tried? At this site it is expected that you show some research effort

Comment: While it seems quite easy to achieve the desired output from your sample input, I have trouble matching them to the description of what you want " match shortest content by key words". Could your rephrase? Or remove the description and provide several more pairs of sample input and desired output. Also (agreeing with Hakon), even as a beginner, you should have made some experimental coding yourself. Please show them, and what output you achieved and describe in which way it is wrong.

Comment: You might want to take the [tour], read [ask] and try to make a [mcve].

Comment: You should probably rewrite your question, it is almost exclusively a regular expression question. Also it would be nice if you could ask a generalized question which is relevant to a broader audience. In any case the way you solve such issues is by heading over to https://regex101.com/r/k4YNwT/1 Oh and do not forget to donate, those guys deserve it.

Comment: Update the question rather than posting comments - what you've written is unreadable

Comment: Update the my question.

Comment: If you have scalar variables called `$braces`, `$braces2`, `$braces3`, etc., then you probably want an array called `@braces`.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works for your example, but I'm not sure I understood you completely. You may need to be a bit more precise.
`^.*?(?=\s*:)|(?<=\[\s{3}).*?(?=\s*\])|(?<=\])\w+`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/A4gwWD/1)

Comment: Thank you for your support, my question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
my $txt='RMS Power                     :  [   0.00]>[   2.83]<[   4.00]dBm        [PASS]';

$re='(.*)\s*:\s*\[\s*(.*)\]>\[\s*(.*)\]<\[\s*(.*)\](.*)\[.*\]';
if ($txt =~ m/$re/is)
{
    $sbraces1=$1;
    $sbraces2=$2;
    $sbraces3=$3;
    $sbraces4=$4;
    $sbraces5=$5;
    print "$sbraces1 $sbraces2 $sbraces3 $sbraces4 $sbraces5 \n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, my question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

my $re = qr/^(.+?)\s+:\s+\[\s*(\S+?)\]>\[\s*(\S+?)\]<\[\s*(\S+?)\](\S+)/;
my $txt='RMS Power                     :  [   0.00]>[   2.83]<[   4.00]dBm        [PASS]';
my @results = $txt =~  $re;
say Dumper\@results;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'RMS Power',
          '0.00',
          '2.83',
          '4.00',
          'dBm'
        ];
```

**Regex explanation:**

```
^           : start of string
  (.+?)     : group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
  \s+       : 1 or more spaces
  :         : semicolon
  \s+       : 1 or more spaces
  \[\s*     : open bracket followed by 0 or more spaces
  (\S+?)    : group 2, 1 or more non space, not greedy
  \]>\[\s*  : close bracket, greater than, open bracket, 0 or more spaces
  (\S+?)    : group 3, 1 or more non space, not greedy
  \]>\[\s*  : close bracket, greater than, open bracket, 0 or more spaces
  (\S+?)    : group 4, 1 or more non space, not greedy
  \]        : close bracket
  (\S+)     : group 5, 1 or more non space
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, my question has been resolved.

Comment: @AllenLee: That's fine, but how? If you have a solution, answer your own question for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is more than one way to do it, I post my own. In this way you simply can achieve what you want without making the pattern complicated.

here it the pattern:

```
[^ [\]:><]+
```

that is it.
It matches all things except those in the character-class. Thus it matches:

```
perl -lne 'print $& while/[^[:><\] ]+/g ' file
RMS
Power
0.00
2.83
4.00
dBm
PASS
```

And without `g` flag it only outputs: `RMS`
And it is the key, that you can repeat this pattern an many as you want to match more than one, for example:

```
([^ [\]:><]+)\s*([^ [\]:><]+)
```

matches: `RMS` and `Power`

The only thing you should think of is "match" between the pattern, that they are

```
(pattern \s* pattern) \D* (pattern) \D* (pattern) \D* (pattern) \W* (pattern)
```

and it can be done in **22** steps

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4gwWD/2)